# Creating a list

Tags: python, list, split

I got this problem where I'm supposed to write a program that eats a few words (seperated by commas) and spits out a clean list with theese words. I cant get my problem to work. Any ideas?

```
def wordlist(word):
    return word.split(',')    

def main ():    
    sentence = input("write a few words and seperate them with , ")
    splitsentence = wordlist(sentence)
    for item in splitsentence:
        print(item)

main()
```

Comment: Is this python 2 or python 3? If it is python 2 you should replace `input()` with `raw_input()`. If you are getting errors you should post them, if your output is different than expected you should post it and your expected output.

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description. What is this code doing, if not what you wrote it to do?

Comment: Your indentation is messy, how did it not raise an error?

Comment: It's python 3. The identation got wrong when i copy pasted, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing the list every time instead of the specific item that you're iterating on:

Instead of `print(splitsetnence)`, you need `print(item)`

```
def main():
    sentence = input("write a few words and separate them with ,")
    splitsentence = wordlist(sentence)
    for item in splitsentence:
        print (item)
```

Also, be conscious of your indentation. The code in the original post does not look correctly indented.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute input() with raw_input().

Comment: If this is the case, then he should also change `print(...)` to `print ...`

Comment: `print()` works in Python 2.7 as well; you can use either `print()` or `print ...`.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: it'll usually work syntactically, but has different semantics: `print(2,3)` gives different results in each.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is off and you should use `raw_input` to get strings:

```
def wordlist(word):
    return word.split(',')


def main():
         sentence = raw_input("write a few words and seperate them with , ")
         splitsentence = wordlist(sentence)
         for item in splitsentence:
             print(item)
main()
```

Also, for such a small task, you can remove the `wordlist(word)` function:

```
def main():
         sentence = raw_input("write a few words and seperate them with , ")
         splitsentence = wordlist.split(')
         for item in splitsentence:
             print(item)
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `raw_input` instead of `input` and substitute `print(splitsentence)` with `print(item)`.

Keep in mind that indentation is Python’s way of grouping statements, like C or Java uses `{` and `}`

Here's my version of your code:

```
sentence = raw_input("write a few words and seperate them with , ")
splitsentence = sentence.split(',')
for item in splitsentence:
    print item
```

This code doesn't require `def main()` or the other lines.